# Remote IP on a local device

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing, openvpn

What I want to achieve is to be able to have one of the IP addresses from a remote server on a local server (raspberry pi).
Right now the network map would look like this:

```
RPi (192.168.0.42) ---> Router/Modem (192.168.0.1) ---> Internet (82.158.xxx.xxx) ---> Remote server (92.xxx.xxx.xxx)
```

The remote server has around 5 IP addresses assigned to it however, what I want to do is use one of those IP addresses locally on my RPi as an assigned IP to an interface.

I've tried OpenVPN but the only issue I have with it is it seems to pull from a remote virtual IP pool rather than letting the RPi use the single remote IP. Or is there something I need to do with OpenVPN to get it to use just one IP?

Either way, my question is this, is there a way to get one of my remote servers IP's registered on my Raspberry Pi under an interface and allow it to be used as a second IP from my home's IP via my Raspberry Pi with all ports usable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's trivial to assign an extra IP to the RPi, the problem is making that address reachable. Inside your network, you could add a host route for all your local devices; not necessarily supported (phones, tablets...). To have the address reachable from the Internet, the short answer is "no chance", and the long answer involves spending a very large amount of money. Can you explain what you want to *do* with the extra address?

Answer (score 0):

If your router allows to add manual routes, this is possible. However it's never a good idea to add funny routings, especially when it comes to faking official ip addresses. Maybe you want explain why you want to do this. There might be an alternative/eysier solution for your requirement.

Comment: Purely for experimentation and learning, it's not to fake the official IP address just to add another one alongside it. As for adding static routes, I can't unfortunately do that with my current router as it's a stock ISP router/modem combo one and I'm too poor to get a separate one.